# Color a mesh by point-wise distance to another mesh while taking relative position of the meshes into consideration

Tags: r, colors, 3d, heatmap, rgl

I have an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196381/how-to-create-heatmap-illustraing-mesh-differences-controlling-the-position-of-c) that asked how to create heatmap that demonstrated differences between two meshes. That post was about how to choose color scales. In order for color to be assigned, vertex-wise distance between the two meshes under comparison must be calculated in the first place. In that post, this was done by the `meshDist` function in Morpho package in R.

What eludes me is that I do not particularly understand how vertex-wise distance was calculated under the hood by `meshDist`. What I want is Euclidean distance between homologous vertex on two meshes (for example, (x1, y1, z1) on mesh1 is homologous to (x2, y2, z2) on mesh2), which is estimated as `sqrt(sum((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2))`. However, this gives somewhat different values from those returned by `meshDist`. Of course I could go ahead and directly use the Euclidean distance calculated by myself for plotting heatmap of mesh. But the Euclidean distance does not reflect the relative position of the two meshes.

When two meshes are superimposed, I want the parts where mesh1 is more prominent colored by a different color from that used to signify parts where mesh2 is more prominent. `meshDist` magicially (to me) takes the relative mesh position into consideration. Positive values returned indicate mesh1 is relatively more prominent and negative values indicate mesh2 being more prominent. In contrast, the Euclidean distance I calculated ignored such information. I would like to ask if it is possible to obtain positive and negative Eulcidean distance, as done in `meshDist` so that the resultant heatmap tells not just the magnitude of difference but also the relative postion of the two meshes?

The full code, including plotting mesh and superimpose colors onto it, is as follows:

```
library(Morpho)
library(xlsx)
library(rgl)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyverse)


mshape1 <- read.xlsx("...\\vb1.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)
mshape2 <- read.xlsx("...\\vb2.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)

it <- read.xlsx("...\\it.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)

# Preparation for use in tmesh3d
vb_mat_mshape1 <- t(mshape1)
vb_mat_mshape1 <- rbind(vb_mat_mshape1, 1)
rownames(vb_mat_mshape1) <- c("xpts", "ypts", "zpts", "")

vb_mat_mshape2 <- t(mshape2)
vb_mat_mshape2 <- rbind(vb_mat_mshape2, 1)
rownames(vb_mat_mshape2) <- c("xpts", "ypts", "zpts", "")

it_mat <- t(as.matrix(it))
rownames(it_mat) <- NULL

vertices1 <- c(vb_mat_mshape1)
vertices2 <- c(vb_mat_mshape2)

indices <- c(it_mat)

mesh1 <- tmesh3d(vertices = vertices1, indices = indices, homogeneous = TRUE, 
               material = NULL, normals = NULL, texcoords = NULL)
mesh2 <- tmesh3d(vertices = vertices2, indices = indices, homogeneous = TRUE, 
               material = NULL, normals = NULL, texcoords = NULL)

mesh1smooth <- addNormals(mesh1)
mesh2smooth <- addNormals(mesh2)

# Calculate mesh distance using meshDist function in Morpho package
mD <- meshDist(mesh1smooth, mesh2smooth)
pd <- mD$dists

######################## Assign color to vertext groups ######################## 
nlevel <- 99
# Method suggested by user2554330 [here][1]
limit <- max(abs(pd))
breaks <- -limit + (0:nlevel)*2*limit/nlevel

pd_cut <- cut(pd, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)

col <- hcl.colors(nlevel, "RdBu")
col <- rev(col)

dat_col <- data.frame(pd = pd, pd_cut = pd_cut, group = as.numeric(pd_cut))
dat_col <- dat_col %>% 
           mutate(col = col[dat_col$group])

open3d()
shade3d(mesh1smooth, col=dat_col$col, specular = "#202020", polygon_offset = 1)
```

Another question is although I could produce heatmap using the `shape3d` function above, this function does not by default create color legend. While there are functions for creating heatmaps that allow me to obtain a seeming good color legend by submitting vertex-wise distance to the function, I cannot guaranteen those function creates colors extactly as I did (which is the method suggested by user2554330). How could I accurately create a verticle color legend for my mesh heatmap, with several intermediate colors (including the center color, i.e., the 50th col in code above) matching their corresponding vertex distance values (`pd_cut`)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "homologous" for a mesh?

Comment: The `mshape1` and `mshape2` each contain 7160 vertices. The first vertex for `mshape1` denotes the same position on face as the frist vertex for `mshape2`. This means the first vertex for the two meshes are homologous. In fact, the vertex represented by each line (not just the 1st line) in `mshape1` is homologous to the vertex represented by the line of the same line number in `mshape2`. Knowing which points are homologus ensures that I am calculating the distance between nasal tip point between the two meshes, rather than distance btw nasal tip point on one mesh and eye corner on the other.